# authentication in node js (from json data)

Tags: json, node.js, mongoose

Here is my model in mongoose from which i have to authenticate the user name and password

```
var employee =  
    {
        empCode : { type : String  ,  unique: true ,  required : true },
        firstName : { type : String  , required : true },
        lastName : { type : String },
        email :  { type : String  },
        DOJ :{ type : Date , default: Date.now },
        DOB :{ type : Date  },
        phoneNo : { type : String },
        authentication : 
            {
                username : { type : String },
                password : { type : String }
            },

        status : {type:Boolean}
    };
```

I want to check with authentication in login what i am trying is

```
loginController.prototype.userValidator = function(req , callback){
    objDB.selectOne(objMdlEmployee , { authentication.username : req.username , authentication.password : req.password } , function(err , ObjDocument){

        if(err){        
            callback(false , config.msg.SOMTHING_WRONG);
        }else if(ObjDocument===null){
            callback(false , config.msg.AUTH_FAIL);
        }
        else {      
            req.session.sessUser = {
                userAuthenticate : true, 
                firstName : ObjDocument.firstName,
                employeeId : ObjDocument.employeeId
            }   
            callback(true , 'Valid');
        }
    });
};
```

but it is giving me error

> Unexpected token .
>   at authentication.username

how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Subfields must be quoted like:

```
objDB.selectOne(objMdlEmployee , { 'authentication.username' : req.username , 'authentication.password' : req.password } , function(err , ObjDocument){
```